# How can I group and total amounts with DataTable REACT?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following script, I need to group by the AKONT field and totalize the field by the UM01S field, is it possible?

```
const options = {
UM01S: (item) => <td>{formatColumn('currency',item.UM01S)}</td>,
NAME1: (item) => <td>{item.NAME1 + item.NAME2}</td>,};

const columns = [
    { key: "BUKRS", visible: true, label: "Sociedad ",   _style: { width: "1%" } },
    { key: "AKONT", visible: true, label: "Cuenta Asociada", _style: { width: "1%" }, },
    { key: "KUNNR", visible: true, label: "Cliente", _style: { width: "2%" } },
    { key: "TXT50", visible: true, label: "Texto", _style: { width: "1%" } },
    { key: "WAERS", visible: true, label: "Moneda", _style: { width: "1%" }, },
    { key: "NAME1", visible: true, label: "Nombre", _style: { width: "1%" } },
    { key: "UM01S", visible: true, label: "Saldo Acumulado", _style: { width: "1%" } }
  ];
<DataTable
   usersData={response}
   fields={columns}
   slots={options}
   setCurrentItems={setCurrentItems}
   />
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `mui/x-data-grid`

https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/

```
 <DataGrid
        rows={response ?? []}
        columns={columns}
        pageSizeOptions={[10, 25, 50]}
        slots={{ toolbar: GridToolbar }}
        slotProps={{
          toolbar: {
            showQuickFilter: true,
            quickFilterProps: { debounceMs: 500 },
          },
        }}
      />
```

You can modify and add columns up to your request.

```
const columns = [
 {
   flex: 1,
   field: 'total',
   headerName: 'Total Column',
   renderCell: ({ row }) => (
        // You can do whatever you want
        // row.UM01S + row. AKONT
   ),
 },
// You can add other columns here
]
```

Regards